# Is it possible to use non-letter symbols instead of backslash in the definition of a command?

Tags: macros, catcodes

I am trying to define new commands starting with other symbols instead of the `\(backslash)` The use of `\backslash` is not so intuitively for  non-experienced  LaTeX users. So I would prefer to use ] , [ or / etc.  in many cases! For example I prefer `=acircum` instead of `\acircum` because = looks like a circumflex symbol(on a) ! I tried to use `\active` to activate an = or other character.

For example: I tried to define  new commands starting with `/` like  `/abc` and `/abd` but the following piece of code had no success!

```
\let\slash/
\catcode`/\active \def/abd{abd..}  \def/abc{abc...} Example: /abc  /abd \catcode`/=12 \let/\slash
```

But TeX complained

Use of `/` doesn't match its definition.

How one could define such commands? (I hope my question is not already duplicate! )

Comment: Also note that `\slash` already has a special definition. Don't clobber TeX – it will clobber you right back.

Comment: Don't do it. Using = instead of backlash as the control char will break all sort keyval arguments and I don't dare to image what is will do to the math input. The slash is used in pathes and normal text too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right! I tried to write a code for non mathematicians. So  such changes are going to be used locally(inside an invironent). I hope that I will succeed.

Comment: Imho you are not doing them a favour. All this special syntax will mean that won't be able to use the internet to find help.

Comment: I've recently been designing a language for use in my work – hopefully to be adopted by my coworkers. The keys to a good language include consistency, familiarity, and modularity – you are throwing all of these into the trash. I *urge* you to reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 8):

Do I advise this: No!!!

The catcode of macro escape character is `0`, i.e. the catcode of `/` has to be changed to `0`.

I did not test for the literal `/` however.

You can use `/def/foo{blabla}` then!

```
\catcode`/=0
\def/abd{abd..}
/def/dosomethingstupid{Something not recommended because it looks weird!}

/abd
/dosomethingstupid

\bye
```

Comment: ! I tried your idea with success! Thank you! How one could use your idea locally(inside a special enviroment?) In other words, how one could go back to the normal use of / ? Onother simillar question: How one could define new functions like \mycmd/ or [mycmd/ with 2 symbols (where / gives the END of the mycmd?)

Comment: @kornaros: Actually: I don't recommend this at all!!!!

Comment: I tried to get back to the normal use of / with \catcode`/=12 but this does not work! Any ideas?

Comment: To keep it local, try defining an environment:  `\newenvironment{frontslash}{\catcode`/=0}{\catcode`/=12}`.  Anything between `\begin{frontslash}` and `\end{frontslash}` will have your forward-slash commands available.  Please note that this is still a terrible idea, though, unless you've got a *very* limited use-case.

Answer (score 5):

An expl3 approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\char_set_catcode_escape:N /
\NewDocumentCommand /Abc {} { abc }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
/Abc
\end{document}
```

As I said: ***here be dragons!***

Comment: Of course, `\Abc` wouldn't be any different from `/Abc`.

Comment: Yes xparse is very powerfull! Please, let me  ask you to generalize your unswer to more comlicated cases like [abc/ where the last charecter could be used to point the end of command. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @kornaros There's no need for `xparse`, here.This is just the same as doing  ``\catcode`/=0``

Comment: @kornaros egreg is right; xparse is just what I use to load expl3 (mostly out of habit). You could just as easily use `\usepackage{expl3}…\newcommand/abc{abc}…`. It's just an alternative approach for new code.

Comment: @kornaros for the second question you asked here, refer to `xparse` documentation: `\NewDocumentCommand \Abc {u/} { abc(#1) } \Abc hello/`

Comment: Note this is the same as `\def\blah#1/{abc(#1)}` – though arguably clearer and certainly more consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than redefine `/` to have the meaning of `\`, you could use LuaLaTeX and (a) set up a function that changes all instances of `/` in the text to `\` "on the fly" and (b) assign this function to the so-called `process_input_buffer` callback, which does its work at a very early stage of processing, *before* (La)TeX does any of its usual work.

Of course, if you do need a forward-slash symbol in your document, you can no longer enter it as `/`; instead, you'll need to write `/slash`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function slash2bslash ( line )
    return line:gsub ( "/", "\\" )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% add the Lua function to "process_input_buffer" callback:
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback
    ( "process_input_buffer", slash2bslash, "slash2bslash" )}} 

\begin{document}
/section{Hello}
/section{Good-bye}
/end{document}
```

Comment: @kornaros - LuaTeX has opened up TeX's paragraph building process, by providing "callbacks" that operate at various stages of the process. The `process_input_buffer` callback is one of these callbacks, and it indeed offers all kinds of possibilities for pre-processing.

Comment: @kornaros Just be careful. It's *so easy* to break things this way – especially if you have no idea what you're actually doing.

Comment: @kornaros If you simply *must*, it's much more advisable to do this processing in a separate step – considering only the author's files. Changing TeX's behavior will change it for *all* files used – classes, packages, definitions, etc., etc., *etc.* – this can have absolutely *drastic* consequences.

Comment: @SeanAllred - Note that my answer is "safe" as it does *not* change the TeX's treatment of `/`. Because the Lua function is assigned to the `process_input_buffer` callback, TeX's eyes -- let alone its mouth, stomach, etc -- do not get to see instances of `/` -- they will all have been converted to `\` before TeX starts its own work.

Comment: @Mico but this is the problem: *every* slash will be replaced by a backslash. There only need to be a real slash  somewhere, e.g. in a graphicspath, or in a math and you get (exactly) the same problems as when you  change the catcode of /.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I don't think we're actually disagreeing. For sure, I have not claimed anywhere that the OP's objective of making `/` act like `\` was a good idea. (FWIW, I do not think it's a good idea...) The point of my answer is much more narrowly focused: Given that the OP is going to bear the responsibility anyway for ensuring that no "real" `/` characters occur in the input stream (or, alternatively, for ensuring that all real `/` characters are converted to `/slash `), what's the least disruptive/safest way of doing so?

Comment: @Mico: it doesn't matter. If there are no "text slashes" then you can change  the catcode or replace them all by backslashes -- the result is the same. If there are text slashes both methods are unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

The `amstex.tex` style file for Plain TeX had `@` as “alternative escape” and this was also used in `amslatex` (the first port of AMS-TeX to LaTeX), but then abandoned when `amsmath` was issued.

In AMS-TeX one could type `@>f>g>` for what would be typed `\xrightarrow[g]{f}` in `amsmath` (both labels were optional, so `@>>>` meant a right pointing arrow). The downside was that a literal `@` had to be input as `@@`.

There was no interface for defining “@-commands”, but there is the `at` package by Mark Wooding that provides it (the documentation can be read with `texdoc mdwtools`, because this points to the first hit, which is exactly `at.sty`).

For instance, the package provides by default the @-command `@/`, whereby

```
@/some text in italics/
```

(note the matching slash at the end) is the same as typing

```
\textit{some text in italics}
```

Also predefined is `@@` for printing an @. Note that `@?` would be different from `\?`: if you do

```
\atdef ?{`?}
\newcommand\?{QQ}
```

the output of `@?` would be different from `\?`.

Of course, one could replicate the code for allowing other prefix characters. The ***big*** downside is that the prefix character must be made into an active one. If you want to use =-commands, such as your proposed `=acircum`, then you can't type `=` in a math formula any more (well, you'd need to be *very* careful).

When `amsmath` was released, AMS thought carefully about @-commands and decided to withdraw them and they had very good reasons for. I'm not sure where `=acircum` could be easier for users than `\acircum`. I'm inclined to believe that they'll be very confused, actually.

You just need to know that commands should be escaped and that the signal for this escape is `\`. Remembering different escapes for different commands would be a nightmare. Possibly funny (I'm writing this answer on All Saints' Eve), but definitely not a good user interface.

---

Other suggested methods such as doing `` \catcode`/=0 `` are quite different.

If you do

```
\catcode`/=0
\newcommand{/Abc}{whatever}
```

you can then call `/Abc` or `\Abc` and this will produce ***exactly*** the same result (unless you also changed the category code of `/`). Of course, you cannot use `/` for printing a slash.

There are good reasons for using the backslash as escape. The character is seldom, if ever, used in running text. For the set theory operation there is the semantically meaningful command `\setminus` (and also the command `\backslash` for the symbol as an ordinary atom). No other character in the ASCII range is in the same situation; except possibly `@` itself (barring its usage in email addresses). Indeed, there is a TeX format that uses `@` and not `\` as escape: it's `texinfo`, that's been used for decades for TeXing documentation in GNU `info` format.